# Can you breed bees in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently I have been playing Minecraft with friends and was instantly intrigued by the newest addition of bees (and other things, but mainly bees) in the 1.15 update. After frantically searching the land for any wandering bees, I found a couple and brought them back to my base. After a couple of Minecraft days, I noticed no change in the bee population and wanted to speed it up. Is there any way to do so, by breeding them, or any other method?

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Bee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bees can be bred with held flowers.